# Is it possible to check for specific jQuery version in if statement

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check to specific version (1.6) of jQuery using an IF statement. I know you can do it for jQuery in general but i need something a little more granular.

Comment: In what situation would you need this? Just reference the version you want.

Comment: Yes. `jQuery.fn.jquery` gives you the version number.

Comment: What prevented you from reading the documentation?

Comment: what do you mean 'in general' and why do you think it cannot be used inside `if`?

Comment: hah, this is a duplicate of a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the jQuery documentation, upon searching for the keyword `"version"`, [tells us](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) to write:

```
alert( 'You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery );
```

and that:

> The `.jquery` property is assigned to the jQuery prototype, commonly referred to by its alias `$.fn`. It is a string containing the version number of jQuery, such as "1.5.0" or "1.4.4".

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
jQuery.fn.jquery;
```

[Blog reference](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-check-jquery-version.html)